# create contingency table from all data in python pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, crosstab, contingency

I have data that has 45222 samples and 13 features. I want to create a contingency table from all data.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = np.genfromtxt(trainFile, delimiter=',')
contingency = pd.crosstab(data)
```

it throws an error of `TypeError: crosstab() missing 1 required positional argument: 'columns'`. Do you know any solution for it.

Comment: Have you tried passing a 'columns' argument as the error message suggests? [doc link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html)

Comment: I used `pd.crosstab(index=data[0], columns = [data[1], data[2],...,data[12]])`. But something is missing. i have 45222 samples. But total count was so less. It was above 50. I don't know whether crosstab is an efficient way of creating contingency tables.

Comment: Do you want a deeply nested contingency table where you're looking at each possible combination of column categories, or are you interested in a separate table for each column?